# Imaginary part of $ \dfrac{ia + b}{ic + d} $ with $a,b,c,d$ real

Tags: complex-numbers

Not quite sure what to do here; how to separate the real and imaginary parts? I've tried changing to polar form but that does not quite help... thanks.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $-ic+d$

Comment: You should get the imaginary part is $$\frac{da-bc}{c^2+d^2}$$

Comment: oh ,yeah that was obvious... ty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what are the conditions for a ratio to be real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562161/what-are-the-conditions-for-a-ratio-to-be-real) The answers also determine the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

This is a standard question. The way to split the real and the imaginary part of $\frac vw$, when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, is to multiply both numbers by $\overline{w}$,

$$\frac vw=\frac{v\overline{w}}{w\overline{w}} = \frac{v\overline{w}}{|w|^2}.$$

Now the denominator is a real number. Can you finish?